# Authorization for Soap Request

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, authorization

So I'm working with a soap request and it is working fine on Soap UI. I'm sending the credentials in Soap UI through the Authorization tab. The problem is when I try to do it using code, the request isn't authorized. Following is the sample code:

```
XmlDocument response = new XmlDocument();
SoapEnvelope soapRequest = new SoapEnvelope();
UsernameToken usr = new UsernameToken("username", "password", PasswordOption.SendNone);
soapRequest.Context.WebRequest.AuthenticationLevel(new CredentialSet(usr));
soapRequest.LoadXml(docx.InnerXml);
SoapEnvelope soapResponse = base.SendRequestResponse(soapAction, soapRequest);
```

Please note that I am using soap client from **Microsoft.Web.Services3**.

Will really appreciate any assistance I can get.

Comment: Are you using credentials with SOAP UI?  You may be using default credentials with SOAP UI and also need to use Defaults Credentials with your WebRequest.

Comment: On Soap UI, I am adding basic authentication to my request and adding the username and password there.

Comment: there arre three reasons for an "unauthorize" 1) the code you posted is failing 2) If you are using HTTPS (secure) the TLS is failing 3) A header is wrong.  For example some websites require certain browsers.  So if the browser is wrong you will fail.  With a Webrequest the browser setting is the UserAgent Header.